# New line after multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all i'm not very experienced with programming so this is probably easy to achieve.

I am pulling data from a mysql table using php i want to display the output like so:

$row[1] $row[2] Line break

$row[3] $row[4] Line break

$row[5] $row[6] Line break

And so on

Any help would be appreciated thanks

```
$user_table = select_table( "users", "user_name ASC" );  
$rows = array( );  

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $user_table ) ) {  
    $rows[] = $row;  
}  

$user_groups = array_chunk( $rows, 2 );  

foreach ( $user_groups as $user_group ) {  

    echo "<tr>";  

    foreach( $user_group as $row ) {  

        echo "<td class=\"user-box\">{$row["user_name"]}</td>";  
    }  
    echo "</tr>";  
}
```

This is my working code. Thanks Tim

Comment: What do you have so far? If you are pulling data using mysql I'm sure you know about the `echo` command.

Comment: How are you "pulling data"?

Comment: `$user_table = select_table( "users", "user_name ASC" );

while( $user = mysqli_fetch_array( $user_table ) ) {
 echo "<div id=\"user-box\">some layout of the users data</div>";
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your results and start counting again after 2.
here's an example using a simple array and a table so you can see how it works

```
<?php

$results = array('one','two','three','four');

echo '<table border="1">';

foreach(array_chunk($results,2) as $row) {

    echo '<tr>';

    foreach($row as $value) {
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: This works great i have updated my first post with my working code.